# Mootools Drag / Loss of focus in iframe

Tags: javascript, iframe, drag

I'm running into a small issue when using Mootools 1.4.5 and the Drag Fx. The problem is that the cursor looses focus when dragging (to the left) because there is a iframe there. I understand why it happens but don't know how to prevent it! Unfortunately, I have to use iframe :(

I'm looking for a solution that either: 1) Prevents the loss of focus or 2) Prevents the mouse from leaving the div area.

Any help would be much appreciated and thanks in advance.

jsfiddle - [Here](http://jsfiddle.net/mac10zig/kzwnw/2/)

Code:

```
    Html:
    <div id="wrap" class="wrap">
        <div id="left" class="left">
            <div id="drag" class="drag"></div>
            <div id="leftContent" class="leftContent">
                <iframe src="http://www.bing.com/"></iframe>
            </div>
        </div>
        <div id="right" class="right">
            <p>You can use the middle slider to adjust the size of the left div which is very cool. But the problem lies when the mouse enters the iframe during the dragging process. This seems to cause a loss of 'focus'. I would find to find a solution that:</p>
            <ul>
                <li>1) Prevents the loss of focus.</li>or
                <li>2) Prevents the mouse from leaving the div area.</li>
            </ul>
        </div>
    </div>

    Mootools/js:
              var leftDrag = new Drag(left, {
                  modifiers: {
                      x: 'width',
                      y: false
                  },
                  limit: {
                      x: [65, wrap.getSize().x - 65]
                  },
                  onDrag: function () {
                      var l = left.getSize().x;
                      right.setStyles({
                          left: l
                      });
                  }
              }).detach();

              drag.addEvents({
                  mouseenter: function () {
                      this.focus();
                      leftDrag.attach();
                  },
                  mouseleave: function () {
                      leftDrag.detach();
                  }

                  //I have have also tried mousedown/mouseup with no luck
              });

    CSS:
    html {
        padding:0;
        margin:0;
        overflow:hidden;
    }
    p {
        text-align:center;
    }
    .left {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        right:50%;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        background:azure;
    }
    .leftContent {
        position:absolute;
        left:0;
        right:5px;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
    }
    .drag {
        position:absolute;
        width:5px;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        right:0;
        background:red;
        border:1px solid black;
        cursor:e-resize;
    }
    .right {
        position:absolute;
        left:50%;
        right:0;
        top:0;
        bottom:0;
        background:yellow;
    }
    iframe {
        height:99%;
        width:99%;
        border:none;
    }
```

**EDIT** - I wound up figuring it out! I just needed to add (this.setCapture/releaseCapture) into the addEvents of the element. I also switched out the mouseenter/mouseleave with mousedown/mouse up. I updated the jsfiddle which can be seen [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mac10zig/kzwnw/5/). Mootools is an awesome library but their documentation is a bit lacking which leads to a lot of guess work :( but luckily for us there is this forum and jsfiddle!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I wound up figuring it out! I just needed to add (this.setCapture/releaseCapture) into the addEvents of the element. I also switched out the mouseenter/mouseleave with mousedown/mouse up. I updated the jsfiddle which can be seen [HERE](http://jsfiddle.net/mac10zig/kzwnw/5/). Mootools is an awesome library but their documentation is a bit lacking which leads to a lot of guess work :( but luckily for us there is this forum and jsfiddle!

```
yourelementid.addEvents({
mousedown:function(){
this.setCapture();
..put your code here element.drag({});
},
mouseup:function(){
this.releaseCapture();
}
});
```